# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' a by Nginx & Vue.js when url with subdirectory

Tags: vue.js, nginx, npm, vue-cli-3

I am developing a Vue.js project with Nginx.
When I build the project by npm as production and access the site via Nginx, I got this syntax error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`.

The URL has a subdirectory like this.

http://localhost:30030/abc

`vue.config.js` uses `publicPath: /abc/`.
Router mode is `hash`.

Vue version is `@vue/cli 4.1.1`.

I need to use subdirectory because the other project uses FQDN (Top directory).

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Has your `vue-router` set?

Comment: Yes. I use vue-router.

Comment: Can you show your code? I don't find the problem without code

Comment: Thanks for your replay  Tingsen Cheng. I understood this issues. It is `nginx.conf`. It needs this config `try_files  $uri.html $uri/index.html $uri =404`.

Comment: But I got the other error which is related this issues.

Comment: I will open question as new one. Thank you.